How can I send messages to myself in a standard person-to-person chat in Discord?
Rationale


I don't see any option to.
An entire server for this purpose is overkill for me.
Other IM platforms (like WhatsApp) allowing this, but hiding the feature, causes me to expect that Discord does too.

Forum Relevance

I wouldn't have considered this to be on-topic were How to send messages to myself on WhatsApp to not exist, but it does, and the answers are useful.

You can't. As you can see in the search bar:

Searching for yourself results in nothing. So does clicking on your name in server(s) and other places.
You could perhaps try to circumvent that by playing with dev tools in Discord web version, e.g. by attempting to send a request to message your ID instead of some other one, but I don't quite see any point of wasting time for it, even if the API allows it.
Another similar solution involves groups that are shown on the screen. You can start a group:

on the top right of the conversations view and then don't invite anyone to it, then in theory you talk to yourself:

As you mentioned, a very quick workaround is to create your own server. It takes 2 minutes. You can then move it to the top of the list and use it whenever you need quick notes - so do I sometimes. You can also improve this by creating few different channel for different types of notes. This would be my most recommended way.

Your point about the API is interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68610809/1 appears to demonstrate that it might be possible to send a message as a user to a user. If that causes Discord to show that message in the message list, that might be a solution. I'll try that someday and report back.
